# Duplicate data source items when selecting an existing content item

Tags: jss

Sitecore version: 9.2

We see duplicates while editing the JSS page in the experience editor.

Steps to replicate:
Add Component -->Select Rendering-->Select an existing content item

[image]

Comment: We got the fix from sitecore support, they provided us an update package for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got the update package for this issue from Sitecore support.

This is the support reference number CS0182754.

Comment: Can you please add a Support Reference number, so anyone facing the same issue in the future can quote it when raising a ticket. Thanks.

Comment: @jammykam just updated the answer with the reference number. Thanks